# How do I read UDP datagrams from a server without first sending a message to the server?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

I have an UDP server that is sending a message every second.
I want to read these messages from a client.
The following client code fails:

```
// client
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const std::string host = "127.0.0.1";
    const int port = 2368;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData); // 2.2 is latest version
    SOCKET socket = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    sockaddr_in server_addr;
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host.c_str());
    int server_struct_length = sizeof(server_addr);
    char readBuffer[100*1000];
    int ret = ::recvfrom(socket, readBuffer, 100*1000, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, &server_struct_length);
    if (ret < 0) {
        int err = WSAGetLastError();
        return err;
    }
}
```

with return value `10022`.
The server code is similar except that

```
::bind(socket, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, server_struct_length);
```

is called before

```
::sendto(socket, buffer, 2050, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, server_struct_length);
```

is called repeatedly:

```
// server
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const std::string host = "127.0.0.1";
    const int port = 2368;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData); // 2.2 is latest version
    SOCKET socket = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    sockaddr_in server_addr;
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host.c_str());
    int server_struct_length = sizeof(server_addr);
    int ret = ::bind(socket, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, server_struct_length);
    if (ret != 0) {
        int err = WSAGetLastError();
        return err;
    }
    char buffer[2050];
    for (;;) {
        ret = ::sendto(socket, buffer, 2050, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, server_struct_length);
        if (ret < 0) {
            int err = WSAGetLastError();
            return err;
        }
        std::cout << "Wrote " << ret << " bytes to 127.0.0.1:2368.\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    }
}
```

The server code does not fail (`sendto` returns 2050).

Comment: Don't bind to `127.0.0.1`. That limits you to only communicating with the localhost. Bind to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: I didn't say anything about sending to `0.0.0.0`. Please confine yourself to what I actually said. Have you considered looking up Winsock error 10013?

Comment: Then the server fails on `sendto()`:
`bind()` to "0.0.0.0" and `sendto()` to "127.0.0.1": error code `10013`.

Comment: Yes, and have you looked it up yet?

Comment: @user207421: I turned off Microsoft Defender Firewall and the server is not failing anymore, but the client still fails.

Comment: 'Fails' how? You're being pretty mingy with your information.

Comment: @user207421: `recvfrom()` returns -1. `WSAGetLastError()`returns `10022`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working:

1. Changed to `bind()` on client and not on server.
2. Used `recv()` instead of `recvfrom()` on client.

Server:

```
   int main(int argc, char* argv[])
   {
      const std::string host = "127.0.0.1";
      const int port = 2368;
      WSADATA wsaData;
      WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData); // 2.2 is latest version
      SOCKET socket = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
      sockaddr_in server_addr;
      server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
      server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
      server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host.c_str());
      int server_struct_length = sizeof(server_addr);
      char buffer[2050];
      for (;;) {
        int ret = ::sendto(socket, buffer, 2050, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, server_struct_length);
        if (ret < 0) {
          int err = WSAGetLastError();
          return err;
         }
         std::cout << "Wrote " << ret << " bytes to 127.0.0.1:2368.\n";
         std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

     }
     return WSACleanup();
   }
```

Client:

```
   int main(int argc, char* argv[])
   {
    const std::string host = "127.0.0.1";
    const int port = 2368;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData); // 2.2 is latest version
    SOCKET socket = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    sockaddr_in server_addr;
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host.c_str());
    int server_struct_length = sizeof(server_addr);
    int ret = ::bind(socket, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, server_struct_length);
    if (ret != 0) {
        int err = WSAGetLastError();
        return err;
    }
    char readBuffer[2050];
    for (;;) {
        ret = ::recv(socket, readBuffer, 2050, 0);
        if (ret < 0) {
            int err = WSAGetLastError();
            std::cerr << "recvfrom() failed. error code: " << err << std::endl;
            return err;
        }
        std::cout << "Read " << ret << " bytes from 127.0.0.1:2368.\n";
    }
    return WSACleanup();
}
```